# Haxe map access with object keys using new but same value key

Tags: hashmap, equality, haxe

The title is a bit confusing. But let me explain my problem.

Let's pretend to have a class called `MyObj`. This `MyObj` has a `hashCode()` function that produces an `Int` hashcode to work with Haxe maps as a key. Like so:

```
var mymap = new Map<MyObj,String>();
var myobj = new MyObj(my,params);
mymap[myobj] = "whatever";
trace(mymap[myobj]); // works great and can print "whatever" from map
```

The above works great.  However; when mapping to a new object of the same parameters it does not work.

```
trace(mymap[new MyObj(my,params)]); // does not work, returns null
```

When printing out and examining the entire map (`trace(mymap)`) it seems that every "new" object that is used as a key is actually a new "id" or "hashcode" (what ever Haxe does under the hood).

I even have the equals operator overloaded in `MyObj` (which can be an abstract type).

The question is, how can you retrieve elements from a map using different objects which contain the same values, as noted above.

how to make something like this work:

```
mymap[new MyObj(my,params)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To offer an alternative to @theRemix's answer: you might want to consider using the [polygonal-ds](https://github.com/polygonal/ds) library. It supports what you're after via its `HashTable` and the `Hashable` interface. Here's a simple usage example:

```
import de.polygonal.ds.HashTable;
import de.polygonal.ds.Hashable;

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var table = new HashTable<MyObj, String>(16);
        table.set(new MyObj(5), "FirstObject");
        table.set(new MyObj(2), "SecondObject");

        trace(table.get(new MyObj(5))); // "FirstObject"
        trace(table.get(new MyObj(0))); // null
    }
}

class MyObj implements Hashable {
    public var key(default, null):Int;

    public function new(key:Int) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

There is one downside: `HashTable` is a class, not an abstract, so it does not support array access.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to use `haxe.ds.HashMap` instead of `Map` for `hashCode` to work?

Comment: hmm hash code seems to work with regular Map; however will try HashMap

Comment: No using haxe.ds.HashMap does not even compile because the object is of an abstract type with equals overloaded and everything

Answer (score 1):

Since they are separate individual objects, this behavior is expected.
To achieve the desired behavior you can

Create a new abstract type from `Map<MyObj,String>` that is internally a `Map<String,String>` when you define the accessors, serialize and deserialize the object key.

Comment: that is a shame it has to be done this way in haxe.. I'm almost considering just using a plain int as the key, eg: calling hashCode() manually.